# appsetting.json and appsettings.Release.json files are not merging after ran the Azure DevOps CI pipeline for .Netcore3.1 project

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-3.1

I have .netcore 3.1 project and in that we have appsettings.json and appsettings.Release.json files for configurations based on the environment.

[image]

here is the launchSettings.json file,

[image]

I'm still able to see these two files in CI artifacts and not at all merging these two files after running the Azure DevOps CI pipeline for this project .
here is the CI artifacts,

[image]

we are using .Netcore 3.1 and I'm not sure why it is not working.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score -1):

CI pipeline Azure devops not merge these three file into single file. this file merge when you publish you code.

[image]

appsettings.json , release.json and development.json this file merg when you publish you code. its not merg when you use CI pipeline.

[image]

More information read these [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#json-variable-substitution-example) on json-variable file